# AWS Amplify with AngularJS brings me a totally css-less template

Tags: aws-amplify

I've created a new AWS amplify application and just followed the guide to add a login validator, the guide I used is [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/hosting/q/integration/angular/), which is the official one, but when I start the application what I've got is this:

[image]

What's wrong???

My styles.css file has the following content

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
```

Answer (score 0):

That guide is outdated. Please use this onehttps://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/getting-started/installation

In short, add this line to your styles.css:

```
@import "@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css";
```